# Add model in tree order with unlimited depth from a list

Tags: python, django, logic

I have the following Category model:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

As you can see, the category can have parent categories and subcategories via ForeignKey.

Now suppose I have this list:

```
Magazines
Magazines/Tech
Magazines/Tech/Network
Magazines/Tech/Programming
Magazines/Tech/Programming/Python
Courses
Courses/Design
Courses/Design/Photoshop
Courses/Tech
Courses/Tech/Programming
```

I need to save each individual category related to it's parent category. Please note that only checking the first parent category isn't enough since `../Tech/Programming` can be found twice, for example. Also, there's not a maximum depth for the tree.

Comment: So I'm confused. What's the question?

Comment: I need to save each individual category related to it's parent category. Eg.: save category Network with parent Tech with parent Magazines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a field where I store the full path of each category. Eg.: `Magazines/Tech/Programming`

So, using that, I loop through the list and check if there's a category with the same fullpath. If there's not, store it with the parent. The revelant code is basically this:

```
def AddCategory(channel, category):
channel = Channel.objects.get(name='Walmart')
if len(category)> 1: # If it's not a root category
    try:
        categoria = Category.objects.get(fullpath=category[0] + "/" + category[1])
        print(categoria.name)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        parent = Category.objects.get(fullpath=category[0])
        new_category = Category.objects.create(name=category[1], channel=channel, parent=parent)
        print(new_category.fullpath)
else: # If it's a root category
    try:
        categoria = Category.objects.get(fullpath=category[0])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        new_category = Category.objects.create(name=category[0], channel=channel)
        print(new_category)
```

I still feel there should be a more elegant way, so feel free to contribute. Thanks!